# button label colour change after click IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a piece of code which creates a button, in the right space size colour etc:

```
UIButton *learnmorebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.view addSubview:learnmorebutton];
learnmorebutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
learnmorebutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 518.0, 159.0, 50.0);
[learnmorebutton setTitle:@"learn more" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[learnmorebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
learnmorebutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:17.0];
```

I then have a trigger for when the button is pressed:

```
[learnmorebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(learnMoreClickEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then I want the buttons background to change and also the text colour, so:

```
sender.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The background changes colour but the text disappears. Like its gone white too.

Comment: The way you changed the color in `learnMoreClickEvent` is different from the one you used in the setting. Try `[sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the color of the label via

```
[sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The button accept no color change on the label directly cause its appearance changes with his state. That is why you need to use the specific [UIButton API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[learnmorebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Change to

```
[learnmorebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

when you click on uibutton get Highlight with white color that why your text  looks like  text disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If you asked "how to change the color when the button is pressed" you can easily change it like this:

```
self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.*yourlabel*.textColor = [UIColor *desiredColor*];
```